# Сортировка datatable в формате min/max

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Всем привет, у меня затык с одним делом 
Мне с бека приходит информация о цене  в формате min/max
И как бы надо сделать сортировку по этому полю, он он обрабатывает ее как строку
И на данный момент у меня нету даже мыслей как лучше это сделать
Может переписать бек, или переписывать функцию сортировки, кто с таким сталкивался? 
заранее спасибо

Comment: _он он обрабатывает ее как строку_, кто он? Приводите строку к числу и все

Answer (score 0):

решил не трогать бек и написать на фронте это

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
"signed-num-pre": function ( a ) {
    let index = a.indexOf('/');
    let number = a.substring(0,index);
    return parseFloat(number);
},

"signed-num-asc": function ( a, b ) {
    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
},

"signed-num-desc": function ( a, b ) {
    return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
}
} );
```